# Transpose rows to columns in Oracle 10g : naming of the columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

My **select** query is as follows :

```
SELECT 
    R.ID_REQUEST, R.ID_PROJET, J.NAME, L.DATE_ACTION,L.NAME_ACTION
    , LEAD(L.DATE_ACTION) OVER (PARTITION BY R.ID_REQUEST ORDER BY L.DATE_ACTION)- L.DATE_ACTION AS TOTAL_DAYS
        FROM (REQUEST R LEFT JOIN LOG_TABLE L ON R.ID_REQUEST = L.ID_REQUEST) 
        LEFT JOIN JOB_TABLE J ON R.ID_JOB = J.ID_JOB
        WHERE D.ID_REQUEST = 10
```

The result is something like this :

```
ID_REQUEST   ID_PROJET  NAME   DATE_ACTION   NAME_ACTION      TOTAL_DAYS
10           152        pr1    01/01/2005    arbitrary_name1  3
10           152        pr1    04/01/2005    arbitrary_name2  1
10           152        pr1    05/01/2005    arbitrary_name3  null
```

what I want is to put the names of the actions as columns. I know that i can do it using `DECODE` (since there is no `pivot`in 10g). but how to use the same name of the action as the name of the column ? The list of actions vary depending on the request. (the table log_table contains the actions per request, the number of actions is variable).
I hope my question is clear enough ! thanks.

Comment: In a regular SQL statement, the column names are fixed.  If you want dynamic column names, you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: can you point me to a tutorial or something ? (btw you answered my last question ! so thanks for your contributions ^^ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This solution](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/) by someone much smarter than I am works well on 10 or 11 with a dynamic number of column.  The only thing it doesn't do is order the columns.
And the implementation

```
SELECT *
    FROM TABLE(DYNAMIC_PIVOT(

                       'SELECT emp_no,dept_no from emp group by emp_no'));




CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PIVOTIMPL AS OBJECT
(
--from here https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/
  RET_TYPE ANYTYPE, -- The return type of the table function
  STMT     VARCHAR2(32767),
  FMT      VARCHAR2(32767),
  CUR      INTEGER,
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCITABLEDESCRIBE(RTYPE  OUT ANYTYPE,
                                    P_STMT IN VARCHAR2,
                                    P_FMT  IN VARCHAR2 := 'upper(@p@)',
                                    DUMMY  IN NUMBER := 0) RETURN NUMBER,
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCITABLEPREPARE(SCTX   OUT PIVOTIMPL,
                                   TI     IN SYS.ODCITABFUNCINFO,
                                   P_STMT IN VARCHAR2,
                                   P_FMT  IN VARCHAR2 := 'upper(@p@)',
                                   DUMMY  IN NUMBER := 0) RETURN NUMBER,
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCITABLESTART(SCTX   IN OUT PIVOTIMPL,
                                 P_STMT IN VARCHAR2,
                                 P_FMT  IN VARCHAR2 := 'upper(@p@)',
                                 DUMMY  IN NUMBER := 0) RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCITABLEFETCH(SELF   IN OUT PIVOTIMPL,
                                 NROWS  IN NUMBER,
                                 OUTSET OUT ANYDATASET) RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCITABLECLOSE(SELF IN PIVOTIMPL) RETURN NUMBER
)
/
prompt
prompt Creating function DYNAMIC_PIVOT
prompt ===============================
prompt
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BROO1APP.DYNAMIC_PIVOT(P_STMT IN VARCHAR2,
                                                  P_FMT  IN VARCHAR2 := 'upper(@p@)',
                                                  DUMMY  IN NUMBER := 0)
  RETURN ANYDATASET
  PIPELINED USING PIVOTIMPL;
/
prompt
prompt Creating type body PIVOTIMPL
prompt ============================
prompt
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY BROO1APP.PIVOTIMPL AS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCITABLEDESCRIBE(RTYPE  OUT ANYTYPE,
                                    P_STMT IN VARCHAR2,
                                    P_FMT  IN VARCHAR2 := 'upper(@p@)',
                                    DUMMY  IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
    ATYP     ANYTYPE;
    CUR      INTEGER;
    NUMCOLS  NUMBER;
    DESC_TAB DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB2;
    RC       SYS_REFCURSOR;
    T_C2     VARCHAR2(32767);
    T_FMT    VARCHAR2(1000);
  BEGIN
    CUR := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(CUR, P_STMT, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS2(CUR, NUMCOLS, DESC_TAB);
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(CUR);
    --
    ANYTYPE.BEGINCREATE(DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_OBJECT, ATYP);
    FOR I IN 1 .. NUMCOLS - 2 LOOP
      ATYP.ADDATTR(DESC_TAB(I).COL_NAME,
                   CASE DESC_TAB(I).COL_TYPE
                     WHEN 1 THEN
                      DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2
                     WHEN 2 THEN
                      DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_NUMBER
                     WHEN 9 THEN
                      DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2
                     WHEN 11 THEN
                      DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 -- show rowid as varchar2
                     WHEN 12 THEN
                      DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_DATE
                     WHEN 208 THEN
                      DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 -- show urowid as varchar2
                     WHEN 96 THEN
                      DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_CHAR
                     WHEN 180 THEN
                      DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP
                     WHEN 181 THEN
                      DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP_TZ
                     WHEN 231 THEN
                      DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP_LTZ
                     WHEN 182 THEN
                      DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_INTERVAL_YM
                     WHEN 183 THEN
                      DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_INTERVAL_DS
                   END,
                   DESC_TAB(I).COL_PRECISION,
                   DESC_TAB(I).COL_SCALE,
                   CASE DESC_TAB(I).COL_TYPE
                     WHEN 11 THEN
                      18 -- for rowid col_max_len = 16, and 18 characters are shown
                     ELSE
                      DESC_TAB(I).COL_MAX_LEN
                   END,
                   DESC_TAB(I).COL_CHARSETID,
                   DESC_TAB(I).COL_CHARSETFORM);
    END LOOP;
    IF INSTR(P_FMT, '@p@') > 0 THEN
      T_FMT := P_FMT;
    ELSE
      T_FMT := '@p@';
    END IF;
    OPEN RC FOR REPLACE('select distinct ' || T_FMT || '
                          from( ' || P_STMT || ' )
                          order by ' || T_FMT,
                        '@p@',
                        DESC_TAB(NUMCOLS - 1).COL_NAME);
    LOOP
      FETCH RC
        INTO T_C2;
      EXIT WHEN RC%NOTFOUND;
      ATYP.ADDATTR(T_C2,
                   CASE     DESC_TAB(NUMCOLS).COL_TYPE WHEN 1 THEN
                   DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 WHEN 2 THEN
                   DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_NUMBER WHEN 9 THEN
                   DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 WHEN 11 THEN
                   DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 -- show rowid as varchar2
                   WHEN 12 THEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_DATE WHEN 208 THEN
                   DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_UROWID WHEN 96 THEN
                   DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_CHAR WHEN 180 THEN
                   DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP WHEN 181 THEN
                   DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP_TZ WHEN 231 THEN
                   DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP_LTZ WHEN 182 THEN
                   DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_INTERVAL_YM WHEN 183 THEN
                   DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_INTERVAL_DS END,
                   DESC_TAB(NUMCOLS).COL_PRECISION,
                   DESC_TAB(NUMCOLS).COL_SCALE,
                   CASE     DESC_TAB(NUMCOLS).COL_TYPE WHEN 11 THEN 18 -- for rowid col_max_len = 16, and 18 characters are shown
                   ELSE     DESC_TAB(NUMCOLS).COL_MAX_LEN END,
                   DESC_TAB(NUMCOLS).COL_CHARSETID,
                   DESC_TAB(NUMCOLS).COL_CHARSETFORM);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE RC;
    ATYP.ENDCREATE;
    ANYTYPE.BEGINCREATE(DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_TABLE, RTYPE);
    RTYPE.SETINFO(NULL,
                  NULL,
                  NULL,
                  NULL,
                  NULL,
                  ATYP,
                  DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_OBJECT,
                  0);
    RTYPE.ENDCREATE();
    RETURN ODCICONST.SUCCESS;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN ODCICONST.ERROR;
  END;
  --
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCITABLEPREPARE(SCTX   OUT PIVOTIMPL,
                                   TI     IN SYS.ODCITABFUNCINFO,
                                   P_STMT IN VARCHAR2,
                                   P_FMT  IN VARCHAR2 := 'upper(@p@)',
                                   DUMMY  IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
    PREC     PLS_INTEGER;
    SCALE    PLS_INTEGER;
    LEN      PLS_INTEGER;
    CSID     PLS_INTEGER;
    CSFRM    PLS_INTEGER;
    ELEM_TYP ANYTYPE;
    ANAME    VARCHAR2(30);
    TC       PLS_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    TC := TI.RETTYPE.GETATTRELEMINFO(1,
                                     PREC,
                                     SCALE,
                                     LEN,
                                     CSID,
                                     CSFRM,
                                     ELEM_TYP,
                                     ANAME);
    --
    IF INSTR(P_FMT, '@p@') > 0 THEN
      SCTX := PIVOTIMPL(ELEM_TYP, P_STMT, P_FMT, NULL);
    ELSE
      SCTX := PIVOTIMPL(ELEM_TYP, P_STMT, '@p@', NULL);
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCICONST.SUCCESS;
  END;
  --
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCITABLESTART(SCTX   IN OUT PIVOTIMPL,
                                 P_STMT IN VARCHAR2,
                                 P_FMT  IN VARCHAR2 := 'upper(@p@)',
                                 DUMMY  IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
    CUR         INTEGER;
    NUMCOLS     NUMBER;
    DESC_TAB    DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB2;
    T_STMT      VARCHAR2(32767);
    TYPE_CODE   PLS_INTEGER;
    PREC        PLS_INTEGER;
    SCALE       PLS_INTEGER;
    LEN         PLS_INTEGER;
    CSID        PLS_INTEGER;
    CSFRM       PLS_INTEGER;
    SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR2(30);
    TYPE_NAME   VARCHAR2(30);
    VERSION     VARCHAR2(30);
    ATTR_COUNT  PLS_INTEGER;
    ATTR_TYPE   ANYTYPE;
    ATTR_NAME   VARCHAR2(100);
    DUMMY2      INTEGER;
    FIRST_COL   VARCHAR2(30);
  BEGIN
    CUR := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(CUR, P_STMT, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS2(CUR, NUMCOLS, DESC_TAB);
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(CUR);
    --
    FOR I IN 1 .. NUMCOLS - 2 LOOP
      T_STMT := T_STMT || ', "' || DESC_TAB(I).COL_NAME || '"';
    END LOOP;
    --
    TYPE_CODE := SCTX.RET_TYPE.GETINFO(PREC,
                                       SCALE,
                                       LEN,
                                       CSID,
                                       CSFRM,
                                       SCHEMA_NAME,
                                       TYPE_NAME,
                                       VERSION,
                                       ATTR_COUNT);
    FOR I IN NUMCOLS - 1 .. ATTR_COUNT LOOP
      TYPE_CODE := SCTX.RET_TYPE.GETATTRELEMINFO(I,
                                                 PREC,
                                                 SCALE,
                                                 LEN,
                                                 CSID,
                                                 CSFRM,
                                                 ATTR_TYPE,
                                                 ATTR_NAME);
      T_STMT    := T_STMT ||
                   REPLACE(', max( decode( ' || SCTX.FMT || ', ''' ||
                           ATTR_NAME || ''', ' || DESC_TAB(NUMCOLS)
                           .COL_NAME || ' ) )',
                           '@p@',
                           DESC_TAB(NUMCOLS - 1).COL_NAME);
    END LOOP;
    T_STMT := 'select ' || SUBSTR(T_STMT, 2) || ' from ( ' || SCTX.STMT || ' )';
    FOR I IN 1 .. NUMCOLS - 2 LOOP
      IF I = 1 THEN
        T_STMT    := T_STMT || ' group by "' || DESC_TAB(I).COL_NAME || '"';
        FIRST_COL := DESC_TAB(I).COL_NAME;
      ELSE
        T_STMT := T_STMT || ', "' || DESC_TAB(I).COL_NAME || '"';
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    T_STMT := T_STMT || ' ORDER BY "' || FIRST_COL || '"';
    --
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(T_STMT);
    SCTX.CUR := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(SCTX.CUR, T_STMT, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    FOR I IN 1 .. ATTR_COUNT LOOP
      TYPE_CODE := SCTX.RET_TYPE.GETATTRELEMINFO(I,
                                                 PREC,
                                                 SCALE,
                                                 LEN,
                                                 CSID,
                                                 CSFRM,
                                                 ATTR_TYPE,
                                                 ATTR_NAME);
      CASE TYPE_CODE
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_CHAR THEN
          DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(SCTX.CUR, I, 'x', 32767);
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 THEN
          DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(SCTX.CUR, I, 'x', 32767);
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_NUMBER THEN
          DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(SCTX.CUR, I, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER));
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_DATE THEN
          DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(SCTX.CUR, I, CAST(NULL AS DATE));
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_UROWID THEN
          DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(SCTX.CUR, I, CAST(NULL AS UROWID));
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP THEN
          DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(SCTX.CUR, I, CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP));
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP_TZ THEN
          DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(SCTX.CUR, I, CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE));
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP_LTZ THEN
          DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(SCTX.CUR, I, CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE));
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_INTERVAL_YM THEN
          DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(SCTX.CUR,
                                 I,
                                 CAST(NULL AS INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH));
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_INTERVAL_DS THEN
          DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(SCTX.CUR,
                                 I,
                                 CAST(NULL AS INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND));
      END CASE;
    END LOOP;
    DUMMY2 := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(SCTX.CUR);
    RETURN ODCICONST.SUCCESS;
  END;
  --
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCITABLEFETCH(SELF   IN OUT PIVOTIMPL,
                                 NROWS  IN NUMBER,
                                 OUTSET OUT ANYDATASET) RETURN NUMBER IS
    C1_COL_TYPE PLS_INTEGER;
    TYPE_CODE   PLS_INTEGER;
    PREC        PLS_INTEGER;
    SCALE       PLS_INTEGER;
    LEN         PLS_INTEGER;
    CSID        PLS_INTEGER;
    CSFRM       PLS_INTEGER;
    SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR2(30);
    TYPE_NAME   VARCHAR2(30);
    VERSION     VARCHAR2(30);
    ATTR_COUNT  PLS_INTEGER;
    ATTR_TYPE   ANYTYPE;
    ATTR_NAME   VARCHAR2(100);
    V1          VARCHAR2(32767);
    N1          NUMBER;
    D1          DATE;
    UR1         UROWID;
    IDS1        INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
    IYM1        INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH;
    TS1         TIMESTAMP;
    TSTZ1       TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
    TSLTZ1      TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE;
  BEGIN
    OUTSET := NULL;
    IF NROWS < 1 THEN
      -- is this possible???
      RETURN ODCICONST.SUCCESS;
    END IF;
    --
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('fetch');
    IF DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(SELF.CUR) = 0 THEN
      RETURN ODCICONST.SUCCESS;
    END IF;
    --
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('done');
    TYPE_CODE := SELF.RET_TYPE.GETINFO(PREC,
                                       SCALE,
                                       LEN,
                                       CSID,
                                       CSFRM,
                                       SCHEMA_NAME,
                                       TYPE_NAME,
                                       VERSION,
                                       ATTR_COUNT);
    ANYDATASET.BEGINCREATE(DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_OBJECT,
                           SELF.RET_TYPE,
                           OUTSET);
    OUTSET.ADDINSTANCE;
    OUTSET.PIECEWISE();
    FOR I IN 1 .. ATTR_COUNT LOOP
      TYPE_CODE := SELF.RET_TYPE.GETATTRELEMINFO(I,
                                                 PREC,
                                                 SCALE,
                                                 LEN,
                                                 CSID,
                                                 CSFRM,
                                                 ATTR_TYPE,
                                                 ATTR_NAME);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ATTR_NAME);
      CASE TYPE_CODE
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_CHAR THEN
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(SELF.CUR, I, V1);
          OUTSET.SETCHAR(V1);
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 THEN
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(SELF.CUR, I, V1);
          OUTSET.SETVARCHAR2(V1);
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_NUMBER THEN
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(SELF.CUR, I, N1);
          OUTSET.SETNUMBER(N1);
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_DATE THEN
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(SELF.CUR, I, D1);
          OUTSET.SETDATE(D1);
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_UROWID THEN
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(SELF.CUR, I, UR1);
          OUTSET.SETUROWID(UR1);
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_INTERVAL_DS THEN
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(SELF.CUR, I, IDS1);

          OUTSET.SETINTERVALDS(IDS1);
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_INTERVAL_YM THEN
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(SELF.CUR, I, IYM1);
          OUTSET.SETINTERVALYM(IYM1);
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP THEN
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(SELF.CUR, I, TS1);
          OUTSET.SETTIMESTAMP(TS1);
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP_TZ THEN
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(SELF.CUR, I, TSTZ1);
          OUTSET.SETTIMESTAMPTZ(TSTZ1);
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP_LTZ THEN
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(SELF.CUR, I, TSLTZ1);
          OUTSET.SETTIMESTAMPLTZ(TSLTZ1);
      END CASE;
    END LOOP;
    OUTSET.ENDCREATE;
    RETURN ODCICONST.SUCCESS;
  END;
  --
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCITABLECLOSE(SELF IN PIVOTIMPL) RETURN NUMBER IS
    C INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    C := SELF.CUR;
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(C);
    RETURN ODCICONST.SUCCESS;
  END;
END;
/
```

Comment: That's a pretty good function ! thanks. I'll try to find a workaround to order the columns (it's important in my case)..if you have any idea to help that would be great !

Comment: @RidRoid In the code I tried to do  this by ordering by the first column from the select.  See the prepare statement.  This did not work for one of my queries where I was concatenating row names into columns for a straight select it should do

Comment: can you share with me your edit please ? I did not spot the difference between your function and the original (from the blog)

Comment: @RidRoid in the prepare part of the type I added   a variable called FIRST_COL that is added at the end as an order by.  But...this does not allow you order the pivot columns.FOR I IN 1 .. NUMCOLS - 2 LOOP
      IF I = 1 THEN
        T_STMT    := T_STMT || ' group by "' || DESC_TAB(I).COL_NAME || '"';
        FIRST_COL := DESC_TAB(I).COL_NAME;
      ELSE
        T_STMT := T_STMT || ', "' || DESC_TAB(I).COL_NAME || '"';
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    T_STMT := T_STMT || ' ORDER BY "' || FIRST_COL || '"';